# Inject bean dependency into Spring application context

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have this class that creates an application context from XML:

```
public class SpringModel {
    public SpringModel(Object dependency) {
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(...);
        Foo foo = (Foo) applicationContext.getBean("foo");
    }
}
```

The bean named "foo" has a constructor that looks like this:

```
public Foo(Object dependency) {
    ...
}
```

I want to inject the argument from `SpringModel`'s constructor into the constructor for `Foo`. Is this possible?

Comment: If you're using component scan, you can wire constructor dependencies with @Autowired.  You can use Qualifier annotation with it to narrow down the bean if there are multiple matches.

Comment: here is a nice write up on the topic. http://www.baeldung.com/constructor-injection-in-spring

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an xml based application context you could define the dependencies like

```
  <beans>
    <bean id="dependencyObj" class="Object"/>

    <bean id="springModelObj" class="SpringModel">
        <constructor-arg ref="dependencyObj"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="foo" class="Foo">
      <constructor-arg ref="dependencyObj" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

It might also be easier to have your Foo object reference be a private variable in the SpringModel class with an appropriate setter method. Then you could link it to the SpringModel bean in the xml configuration with a property tag.